# Struts 2 populate multiple propeties of bean on form submission with s:select tag

Tags: select, struts2, form-submit

I have a select tag which populates list of ClientBean objects. ClientBean object has two properties clientId and clientName. I have set multiple equal to true so that I can select multiples options. Following is my select tag

```
 <s:select name="clientBeans.clientId" id="clientBeansItr" multiple="true"
        list="clientBeans" listKey="clientId" listValue="clientName" 
        value="%{selectedClients}" />
```

Above select box properly shows all the clients and selected clients in dropdown. selectedClients is list of integers which represent cleintIds of already selected clients.
      Now when I submit the form which contains this select tag ProjectBean class which is model for the action that gets invoked on submission of form correctly poulates number of selected clients in List of ClientBeans and sets the clientId property for each of the ClientBean objects. However I would like to set clientName property as well along with clientId property when I submit the form. How to achieve this? PFB additional code for ProjectBean and ClientBean class.

```
     class ProjectBean{

            ....

            private List<ClientBean> clientBeans;

            ...has its getters and setters...
     }   


     class ClientBean{

           private Integer clientId;

           private String clientName;

           .....
              getters and setters

           ......
     }
```

Comment: This is how html select tag works. Pass id to the action and in the action class get client by that id.

Comment: Also title of this post is not relevant to the question asked.

Comment: @AleksandrM Ok. So is there no way to populate multiple properties of bean automatically?

Comment: Of course there *are* ways. E.g. use js to set some hidden fields or whatever. But it is not a best practice.

Comment: @AleksandrM Correct I had thought of that. I mean to say Aren't there any "clean"and "struts2" ways to do it?

Comment: No *clean* ways. If you already have a list of clients you can cache it and after submit get client by id.